# How to make .bat do not call cmd

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Soo 
`@echo off` Turn off command echoing and don't echo the command turning it off. But how to make bat file do not call CMD at all ?

Comment: I've got to say, this has to be the most confusing, _(impossible to understand)_, question I have encountered on this site. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48138288/edit), to clarify.

Comment: I'm confused but I suppose you don't want to see the cmd.exe window while your bat is running.If so you can check [this](https://superuser.com/a/872858/62798) or [this](https://superuser.com/a/1187025/62798)

Comment: Batch *IS* cmd. You can't run a batch script in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This makes so little sense. If you're asking how to **stop a batch file from showing the command prompt window**, you cannot.

You can however use a VBScript file to launch the batch file silently. The script would look something like:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\path-to-batch-file\batchfile.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I think what you're trying to do probably isn't a job for a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

A batch file is a **script**, not a **binary executable**. A script always needs an interpreter to run. For batch scripts, the interpreter is `cmd.exe`, so you cannot avoid invoking `cmd.exe` at all. It makes no sense to run a script without its interpreter. This is true everywhere.

All you can do is hiding the console window that `cmd.exe` brings up when it's invoked, most easily done with the help of a VBScript:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\path\to\your.bat", 0, False
```